# Map of an expression in a 3D grid is very slow

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, parallelization, map

I have a quite large expression as function of $R$, $\phi$ and $Z$ as you can see:

```
expression = (0. + 1/10 (5/R^6 + 5 R^4) Z (0. + 1.5 Cos[5 \[Phi]]) + ((
  30 R + 90 R^9 - 120 R^11)/(
  480 R^5) - (-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 10 R^12)/(96 R^6) + 
  1/4 (-(5/R^6) + 5 R^4) Z^2) (0. + 
  1.5 Sin[5 \[Phi]]) + (((-1 + R^2)^4 (46 R + 76 R^3 + 60 R^5))/(
  26880 R^5) + ((-1 + R^2)^3 (18 + 23 R^2 + 19 R^4 + 10 R^6))/(
  3360 R^4) - ((-1 + R^2)^4 (18 + 23 R^2 + 19 R^4 + 10 R^6))/(
  5376 R^6) + 
  1/2 ((30 R + 90 R^9 - 120 R^11)/(
     480 R^5) - (-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 10 R^12)/(96 R^6)) Z^2 + 
  1/48 (-(5/R^6) + 5 R^4) Z^4) (0. + 
  10. Sin[5 \[Phi]]))/(\[Sqrt]((0. + 1/R + (
   5 ((-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 10 R^12)/(480 R^5) + 
      1/4 (1/R^5 + R^5) Z^2) (0. + 1.5 Cos[5 \[Phi]]))/R + (
   5 (((-1 + R^2)^4 (18 + 23 R^2 + 19 R^4 + 10 R^6))/(
      26880 R^5) + ((-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 10 R^12) Z^2)/(
      960 R^5) + 1/48 (1/R^5 + R^5) Z^4) (0. + 
      10. Cos[5 \[Phi]]))/
   R + ((-(1/R^5) + R^5) Z (0. - 1.5 Sin[5 \[Phi]]))/(
   2 R))^2 + (0. + 
   1/10 (-(1/R^5) + R^5) (0. + 1.5 Cos[5 \[Phi]]) + 
   1/2 (1/R^5 + R^5) Z (0. + 
      1.5 Sin[5 \[Phi]]) + (((-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 
         10 R^12) Z)/(480 R^5) + 1/12 (1/R^5 + R^5) Z^3) (0. + 
      10. Sin[5 \[Phi]]))^2 + (0. + 
   1/10 (5/R^6 + 5 R^4) Z (0. + 1.5 Cos[5 \[Phi]]) + ((
      30 R + 90 R^9 - 120 R^11)/(
      480 R^5) - (-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 10 R^12)/(96 R^6) + 
      1/4 (-(5/R^6) + 5 R^4) Z^2) (0. + 
      1.5 Sin[5 \[Phi]]) + (((-1 + R^2)^4 (46 R + 76 R^3 + 
         60 R^5))/(
      26880 R^5) + ((-1 + R^2)^3 (18 + 23 R^2 + 19 R^4 + 
         10 R^6))/(
      3360 R^4) - ((-1 + R^2)^4 (18 + 23 R^2 + 19 R^4 + 10 R^6))/(
      5376 R^6) + 
      1/2 ((30 R + 90 R^9 - 120 R^11)/(
         480 R^5) - (-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 10 R^12)/(
         96 R^6)) Z^2 + 1/48 (-(5/R^6) + 5 R^4) Z^4) (0. + 
      10. Sin[5 \[Phi]]))^2))
```

I need to evaluate this expression in the following 3D grid

```
grid = Table[{(i+1/2)*5,(j+1/2)*5,k*0.0785},{i,0,119},{j,0,159},{k,0,79}]
```

and I'm doing that with the ParallelMap:

```
result = ParallelMap[expression /. {R -> #[[1]], \[Phi] -> #[[2]], Z -> #[[3]]} &, grid, {3}]
```

However this takes about 4min which is quite a lot since I have to do this for a bunch of other large expressions. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: Without expression, we cannot tell you anything. Place the code in place of the picture.

Comment: I just added the code for the expression.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like `expression` is periodic on   $\phi $ with a period $2\pi /5$. Why do you use `(j+1/2)*5,{j,0,159}` to map it?

Comment: Yes, indeed this particular expression has period of 5 in $\phi$, but I have a few more expressions which I need to evaluate, and which are not $\phi$ periodic...

Comment: What are these huge `result` for?

Comment: I checked that `ParallelTable[]` finds the `result` 2 times faster: `result = 
 ParallelTable[
  expression /. {R -> (i + 1/2)*5., \[Phi] -> (j + 1/2)*5, 
    Z -> k*0.0785}, {i, 0, 119}, {j, 0, 159}, {k, 0, 79}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can reduce the time by 100 times using `Compile[]` and `ParallelTable[]`

```
cf = Compile[{{R, _Real}, {\[Phi], _Real}, {Z, _Real}}, (0. + 
     1/10 (5/R^6 + 5 R^4) Z (0. + 
        1.5 Cos[5 \[Phi]]) + ((30 R + 90 R^9 - 
           120 R^11)/(480 R^5) - (-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 
           10 R^12)/(96 R^6) + 1/4 (-(5/R^6) + 5 R^4) Z^2) (0. + 
        1.5 Sin[5 \[Phi]]) + (((-1 + R^2)^4 (46 R + 76 R^3 + 
             60 R^5))/(26880 R^5) + ((-1 + R^2)^3 (18 + 23 R^2 + 
             19 R^4 + 10 R^6))/(3360 R^4) - ((-1 + R^2)^4 (18 + 
             23 R^2 + 19 R^4 + 10 R^6))/(5376 R^6) + 
        1/2 ((30 R + 90 R^9 - 120 R^11)/(480 R^5) - (-14 + 15 R^2 + 
              9 R^10 - 10 R^12)/(96 R^6)) Z^2 + 
        1/48 (-(5/R^6) + 5 R^4) Z^4) (0. + 
        10. Sin[5 \[Phi]]))/(Sqrt[((0. + 
          1/R + (5 ((-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 10 R^12)/(480 R^5) + 
               1/4 (1/R^5 + R^5) Z^2) (0. + 1.5 Cos[5 \[Phi]]))/
           R + (5 (((-1 + R^2)^4 (18 + 23 R^2 + 19 R^4 + 
                    10 R^6))/(26880 R^5) + ((-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 
                    10 R^12) Z^2)/(960 R^5) + 
               1/48 (1/R^5 + R^5) Z^4) (0. + 10. Cos[5 \[Phi]]))/
           R + ((-(1/R^5) + R^5) Z (0. - 
               1.5 Sin[5 \[Phi]]))/(2 R))^2 + (0. + 
          1/10 (-(1/R^5) + R^5) (0. + 1.5 Cos[5 \[Phi]]) + 
          1/2 (1/R^5 + R^5) Z (0. + 
             1.5 Sin[
               5 \[Phi]]) + (((-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 
                  10 R^12) Z)/(480 R^5) + 
             1/12 (1/R^5 + R^5) Z^3) (0. + 
             10. Sin[5 \[Phi]]))^2 + (0. + 
          1/10 (5/R^6 + 5 R^4) Z (0. + 
             1.5 Cos[
               5 \[Phi]]) + ((30 R + 90 R^9 - 
                120 R^11)/(480 R^5) - (-14 + 15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 
                10 R^12)/(96 R^6) + 1/4 (-(5/R^6) + 5 R^4) Z^2) (0. + 
             1.5 Sin[
               5 \[Phi]]) + (((-1 + R^2)^4 (46 R + 76 R^3 + 
                  60 R^5))/(26880 R^5) + ((-1 + R^2)^3 (18 + 23 R^2 + 
                  19 R^4 + 10 R^6))/(3360 R^4) - ((-1 + R^2)^4 (18 + 
                  23 R^2 + 19 R^4 + 10 R^6))/(5376 R^6) + 
             1/2 ((30 R + 90 R^9 - 120 R^11)/(480 R^5) - (-14 + 
                   15 R^2 + 9 R^10 - 10 R^12)/(96 R^6)) Z^2 + 
             1/48 (-(5/R^6) + 5 R^4) Z^4) (0. + 
             10. Sin[5 \[Phi]]))^2)])]
result = ParallelTable[
    cf[(i + 1/2)*5., (j + 1/2)*5, k*0.0785], {i, 0, 119}, {j, 0, 
     159}, {k, 0, 79}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes few seconds with 4 kernels.

Comment: I didn't know this Compile function of Mathematica. Great! With two kernels it takes me now 3s. Thanks!

Comment: @AJHC You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `FunctionCompile` (I also called `Simplify` on `expression` first):

```
cf=FunctionCompile[Function[{}, Table[With[{R = (i + 0.5)*5, \[Phi] = (j + 0.5)*5, Z = k*0.0785}, 
      ((5. + 5.*R^10)*Z*Cos[5*\[Phi]] + (1.2351190476190474 - 0.08680555555555555*R^4 + 0.22321428571428573*R^14 - 7.6388888888888875*Z^2 - 
          6.944444444444444*Z^4 + R^12*(-1.8229166666666667 - 4.861111111111111*Z^2) + R^2*(-0.5729166666666666 - 3.125*Z^2) + 
          R^10*(1.0243055555555556 + 15.624999999999998*Z^2 + 6.944444444444444*Z^4))*Sin[5*\[Phi]])/
       (R^6*Sqrt[(1/R^12)*(44.444444444444436*(R^5 + (-0.18526785714285715 + 0.06510416666666667*R^4 + 0.018601190476190476*R^14 + 
                1.1458333333333333*Z^2 + 1.0416666666666667*Z^4 + R^12*(-0.1953125 - 0.5208333333333334*Z^2) + R^2*(0.14322916666666666 + 0.78125*Z^2) + 
                R^10*(0.15364583333333334 + 2.34375*Z^2 + 1.0416666666666667*Z^4))*Cos[5*\[Phi]] + (0.75 - 0.75*R^10)*Z*Sin[5*\[Phi]])^2 + 
           1.*R^2*((1. - 1.*R^10)*Cos[5*\[Phi]] + Z*(-3.055555555555555 - 2.083333333333333*R^2 + 1.3888888888888886*R^12 - 5.5555555555555545*Z^2 + 
                R^10*(-6.249999999999999 - 5.5555555555555545*Z^2))*Sin[5*\[Phi]])^2 + 48.22530864197531*
            ((0.72 + 0.72*R^10)*Z*Cos[5*\[Phi]] + (0.17785714285714285 - 0.0125*R^4 + 0.03214285714285714*R^14 - 1.0999999999999999*Z^2 - 1.*Z^4 + 
                R^12*(-0.2625 - 0.7000000000000001*Z^2) + R^2*(-0.08250000000000002 - 0.45*Z^2) + R^10*(0.1475 + 2.2500000000000004*Z^2 + 1.*Z^4))*Sin[
                5*\[Phi]])^2)])], {i, 0, 119}, {j, 0, 159}, {k, 0, 79}]]];
```

This gives me:

```
In[.]:= (res=cf[];)//AbsoluteTiming
Out[.]= {0.126522,Null}
```

The downside is that `FunctionCompile` itself can take a significant amount of time.

Edit: Same code with with the upper limits as parameters:

```
cf=FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[ii,"MachineInteger"],Typed[jj,"MachineInteger"],Typed[kk,"MachineInteger"]},Table[With[{R=(i+0.5)*5,\[Phi]=(j+0.5)*5,Z=k*0.0785},((5.+5.*R^10)*Z*Cos[5*\[Phi]]+(1.2351190476190474-0.08680555555555555*R^4+0.22321428571428573*R^14-7.6388888888888875*Z^2-6.944444444444444*Z^4+R^12*(-1.8229166666666667-4.861111111111111*Z^2)+R^2*(-0.5729166666666666-3.125*Z^2)+R^10*(1.0243055555555556+15.624999999999998*Z^2+6.944444444444444*Z^4))*Sin[5*\[Phi]])/(R^6*Sqrt[(1/R^12)*(44.444444444444436*(R^5+(-0.18526785714285715+0.06510416666666667*R^4+0.018601190476190476*R^14+1.1458333333333333*Z^2+1.0416666666666667*Z^4+R^12*(-0.1953125-0.5208333333333334*Z^2)+R^2*(0.14322916666666666+0.78125*Z^2)+R^10*(0.15364583333333334+2.34375*Z^2+1.0416666666666667*Z^4))*Cos[5*\[Phi]]+(0.75-0.75*R^10)*Z*Sin[5*\[Phi]])^2+1.*R^2*((1.-1.*R^10)*Cos[5*\[Phi]]+Z*(-3.055555555555555-2.083333333333333*R^2+1.3888888888888886*R^12-5.5555555555555545*Z^2+R^10*(-6.249999999999999-5.5555555555555545*Z^2))*Sin[5*\[Phi]])^2+48.22530864197531*((0.72+0.72*R^10)*Z*Cos[5*\[Phi]]+(0.17785714285714285-0.0125*R^4+0.03214285714285714*R^14-1.0999999999999999*Z^2-1.*Z^4+R^12*(-0.2625-0.7000000000000001*Z^2)+R^2*(-0.08250000000000002-0.45*Z^2)+R^10*(0.1475+2.2500000000000004*Z^2+1.*Z^4))*Sin[5*\[Phi]])^2)])],{i,0,ii},{j,0,jj},{k,0,kk}]]];
```

Comment: I have tested this code and it runs on my computer  several minutes to compile and 3.64 s to calculate `res` . How did you get 0.126522 s?

Comment: You're right, in a production version (12.1) I get 1.8 seconds to compute res, and 78 seconds to compile. In the upcoming version (unrelease 12.2) the function evaluation will get a lot faster (but the compilation time goes up a bit). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok! Now I have same time with v.12.1. But if we change parameters like ` {i, 0, 110}, {j, 0, 150}, {k, 0, 100}` then we should compile again and spend time, while with my code we just using same `cf[]` with new parameters.  Could you prepare version with parameters?